# Fourier transform of a $L^1 \cap L^{\infty} $ function is in $L^1$

Tags: proof-verification, fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

I am looking to prove that if $f$ is in $L^1(\mathbb{R}^d) \cap L^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^d)$ and is such that $\hat{f} \geq 0$, then $\hat{f} \in L^1(\mathbb{R}^d)$. Does it suffice to show that the expression
\begin{equation}
\int_{\mathbb{R}^d} e^{-\frac{|x|^2}{2k}}\hat{f}(x) dx  
\end{equation}
converges when $k \rightarrow \infty$ to $\int_{\mathbb{R}^d} \hat{f}(x) dx$, (which it does, by the monotone convergence theorem) and then conclude by observing that the first integrand is in $L^1(\mathbb{R}^d)$ for a fixed $k \in \mathbb{N}$?

Comment: This argument does not exclude that the sequence of integrals tends to $+\infty$.

Comment: Don't we have $e^{-\frac{|x|^2}{2k}} \hat{f}(x) \rightarrow \hat{f}(x)$ in $L^1(\mathbb{R}^d)$, when $k \rightarrow \infty$? Since the converging sequence is $L^1$, isn't the limit as well by completeness of $L^1$?

Comment: Maybe, but you have to work for that, and use some special property of the Fourier transform. It is not obvious at all. For example, the integrals $$\int e^\frac{-|x|^2}{2k}\, dx $$ exist all finite, but in the limit as $k\to\infty$, the sequence of integrals tends to $\infty$.

Comment: What you need to prove is that the sequence $e^{-\frac{|x|^2}{2k} } \hat f$ is $L^1$ Cauchy. This is not obvious.